# What is the point of source tag if the test data is read from the example table? I'm getting the error "Scenrario Outline...has no examples defined"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, specflow

I don't understand how this works. I'm getting the error `Scenrario Outline 'Update password for first-time login' has no examples defined` even though I'm telling Visual Studio to use the source that's housing the test data I want to use.

```
Scenario Outline: Update password for first-time login
    Given I go to the Payee Portal website
    And I enter <username> in the username field
    And I enter <password> in the password field
    And I click sign on to log in
    When I enter old password <password>
    And I enter new password <new password>
    And I click update
    Then I should see the Congratulations Change Password page

@source:TestData.xlsx:Sheet1
Examples:
| username | password  | new password  |
```

My bindings are

```
       [Given(@"I enter (.*) in the username field")]
        public void GivenIEnterInTheUsernameField(string p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0);
        }

        [Given(@"I enter (.*) in the password field")]
        public void GivenIEnterInThePasswordField(string p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0);
        }

        [When(@"I enter old password (.*)")]
        public void WhenIEnterOldPassword(string p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0);
        }

        [When(@"I enter new password (.*)")]
        public void WhenIEnterNewPassword(string p0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p0);
        }

        [Given(@"I click sign on to log in")]
        public void GivenIClickSignOnToLogIn()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        [When(@"I click update")]
        public void WhenIClickUpdate()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }

        [Then(@"I should see the Congratulations Change Password page")]
        public void ThenIShouldSeeTheCongratulationsChangePasswordPage()
        {
            ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
        }
```

When I Build Solution I get said error. However, if I change the source example table to the following:

```
@source:TestData.xlsx:Sheet1
Examples:
| username  | password  | new password |
| username1 | password1 | newpassword2 |
```

The Build Solution works and the test run output is:

```
Given I go to the Payee Portal website
-> done: PayeePortalSteps.GivenIGoToTheWebsite() (3.9s)
And I enter username1 in the username field
username1
-> done: PayeePortalSteps.GivenIEnterInTheUsernameField("username1") (0.0s)
And I enter password1 in the password field
password1
-> done: PayeePortalSteps.GivenIEnterInThePasswordField("password1") (0.0s)
And I click sign on to log in
-> pending: PayeePortalSteps.GivenIClickSignOnToLogIn()
When I enter old password password1
-> skipped because of previous errors
And I enter new password newpassword2
-> skipped because of previous errors
And I click update
-> skipped because of previous errors
Then I should see the Congratulations Change Password page
-> skipped because of previous errors
```

But the thing is, I don't what to use the example as test data. I want to use the test data in the Excel source file. I feel like SpecFlow using the data in the example table defeats the purpose of using a source Excel file. What am I not understanding? Is there a guide to understanding how this set up is supposed to look like?

Comment: Scenario Outlines require the examples data grid. If you want to use an external resource for data, change it from Scenario Outline: to Scenario: and then call the data from the excel file within the step.

Comment: @Dazed the source tag is a feature of SpecFlow+ Excel to get examples out of an excel file.

Comment: @Irving Martinez Could you provide a repo project where we could reproduce this issue?